# How to change data storage location in mysql server

Tags: redmine

I have installed redmine in my ubuntu 12.04 system with mysql server database. Currently the datas are being stored in a default database named mysql. I want to create a new database in the same mysql server and change the location of data storage to the new database. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do

```
RENAME DATABASE mysql TO newDbName;
```

In your code, you can just change the query in the `FROM` statement to your new database and table.

Or, if you were trying to start with a blank slate, then, after creating the new database, run the following:

```
mysqldump -u user -ppass -d olddb | mysql -u user -ppass -D newdb
```

which will copy your old schema to the new db.

Comment: I have a database with the name Redmine. Can I change the data storage location from database named mysql to the one named Redmine without renaming the mysql db? Is there any query for that?

Comment: I tried the second one, but that is giving an error in the sql syntax.   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u root -p -d mysql | mysql -u root -p -D Redmine' at line 1
Has the error occured because I have the old db name as mysql? If yes then how can I solve that error?

Comment: The mysqldump command is for a command line interface, not for use as a query.

Comment: First, look to see if the schema in the new database is correct. That is, all the column names are correct, in the same order, and will take values of the same type. Next, look in redmine's config/database.yml file to change the database name. You will have to "reinstall" Redmine, as it has to repopulate the database with initial data. See http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall.

Comment: By using the 2nd query you suggested, I was able to copy the datas into the new db. Thanks for that. :) But, do I have to repeat it every time some new datas get stored in the database or will the datas be automatically stored into the newly created db?

Comment: The `mysql` database on a MySQL server contains internal data needed for the operation of the database server (like permissions, configuration data, ...) You should **never** move that DB or mess too much with it at all. Your database server will break!